# Swift Firebase UITableViewCell loads before Data to populate cell is available

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I am pushing data which is an array of strings to a tableview controller. These strings are "uid's" which are users in my database. With this array I make a call to firebase to extract all users and then do a match to the uid's. I am getting the correct data, yet I print out everything to make sure when the data is available and the data is available only after the tableview cell loads which causes the data to be nil causing a crash or just empty data. How can I make the data load first and then the cell so the data is available for display?

I've created functions for the data and now I have it in my viewDidLoad. Also, you'll see I have tried adding the firebase call into the Cell setup but of course that does not work.

**Array of strings**

```
var data = [String]()
```

**viewDidLoad**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Database.database().reference().child("Businesses").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            self.businessUID = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                for item in dict {
                    let json = JSON(item.value)
                    let businessUid = json["uid"].stringValue
                    for uid in self.data {
                        if uid == businessUid {
                            let customerValue = self.businessUID?[uid]
                            self.businessDictionary = customerValue as! NSDictionary
                            print(self.businessDictionary)
                            print("Just printed the business dictionary")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("does not exist")
        }
    })
}
```

**Tableview Cell**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomerViewsSelectedBusinessesCell

    print(self.businessDictionary)
    print("Print the dictionary here to check the values")
    let businessValues = self.businessDictionary
    let uid = self.data.description

    print(businessValues)
    print("printed the business values")

    if let dict = businessValues {
        for item in dict {
            let json = JSON(item.value)
            let businessUid = json["uid"].stringValue
            for uid in self.data {
                if uid == businessUid {
                    let customerValue = self.businessUID?[uid]
                    self.businessData = customerValue as? NSDictionary
                    print(self.businessData)
                    print("Printing matching the uid values")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cell.businessName.text = businessData?["businessName"] as? String
    cell.businessStreet.text = businessData?["businessStreet"] as? String
    cell.businessCity.text = businessData?["businessCity"] as? String
    cell.businessState.text = businessData?["businessState"] as? String

    let businessProfilePicture = businessData?["profPicString"] as? String
    if (businessProfilePicture!.characters.count) > 0 {
        let url = URL(string: (businessProfilePicture!))
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)?.potter_circle
                    cell.profileImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
                    cell.profileImage.image = image
                    }
                }
            } else {
        let image = UIImage(named: "default")?.potter_circle
        cell.profileImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        cell.profileImage.image = image
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Hi Frank, nice to see you on one of my posts again. Maybe I just need to create a data structure and then apply the needed data to it. Still I am curious if this current problem can be solved.

Comment: In pretty new to all of this (which is why this isn’t an answer, but a suggestion), but I imagine the stuff inside the Database closure is asynchronous. Because of that, I think you need to call `reloadData()` on the tableview once you’ve got all your data out of fire base and into your controller. This will make the table view rerender because it now knows the data in its data source has changed. Also, I don’t see you actually setting that `var data` to anything. I see you loop over it, but not set it. Are you sure that’s right?

Comment: Makes sense, Ill give it a shot. I don't need to set "var data" only using the uid's inside to make a match then grab all the users data and apply it to a dictionary.

Comment: Yeah reloading the tableview doesn't do it because right from the start there is no data technically so it's going to crash or display nothing because the dictionaries are still technically nil

Comment: And just so we’re on the same page, you put the `reloadData()` call right after setting `businessData`? If so, would you be able to post the data source methods, such as the numberOfRowsInSection method?

Comment: Yes Nate, with my changes and using your solution of adding a "reload" is what got it to work properly. Thank you!

Comment: Hey hey! Awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. Got it to work. Appened and used "usersArray" to get and display the data.

```
var data = [String]()
var usersArray = [NSDictionary?]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Database.database().reference().child("Businesses").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            self.businessUID = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                for item in dict {
                    let json = JSON(item.value)
                    let businessUid = json["uid"].stringValue
                    for uid in self.data {
                        if uid == businessUid {
                            let customerValue = self.businessUID?[uid]
                            self.usersArray.append(customerValue as! NSDictionary)
                            self.followUsersTableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("does not exist")
        }
    })
}


override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.usersArray.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomerViewsSelectedBusinessesCell

    let user : NSDictionary?

    user = self.usersArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.businessName.text = String(user?["businessName"] as! String)
    cell.businessStreet.text = String(user?["businessStreet"] as! String)
    cell.businessCity.text = String(user?["businessCity"] as! String)
    cell.businessState.text = String(user?["businessState"] as! String)

    let businessProfilePicture = String(user?["profPicString"] as! String)
    if (businessProfilePicture.characters.count) > 0 {
        let url = URL(string: (businessProfilePicture))
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)?.potter_circle
                    cell.profileImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
                    cell.profileImage.image = image
                    }
                }
            } else {
        let image = UIImage(named: "default")?.potter_circle
        cell.profileImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        cell.profileImage.image = image
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: why can't you reload data out of  loops ? reloading data in loop is just increasing processing time and application efficiency also its a bad approach.

Comment: Plus also this view controller isn't going to be used a lot, yet I still want to learn how to increase speed and decrease memory.